# Restrict User from Editing Characters after a special character - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a text-field in an HTML form and I have a custom requirement on it.

The field will be automatically filled with a colon (:) and then an 8 digit number on the fly. The user can enter alphanumeric characters before the colon but the users should be restricted from editing the number after the colon (:) inside the text field. Is that possible in Jquery?

```
var input_value = $('#account_no").val();
// Suppose the input_value = '123abc-123:20122015';
```

So, if a user tries to edit the value after the colon, i.e., '20122015', it should be restricted and alert the user. And also, the old value should be retained in the text_field. Is that possible?

```
$('#account_number').live('input propertychange paste', function() {
  // Code to be written
}
```

JQuery Version: `1.8.3`

Comment: `onblur` of that field may be you can do some kind of match with existing string(match only after :)?

Comment: don't put the second part in an input, only the first. More intuitive to users

Comment: Also `live()` has been deprecated for quite a few years

Comment: If the value after `:` is not to be changed, then can you not display this value in a `label` next to the input field? Not allowing the user to edit what he can't is better UX practice.

Comment: @VikramDeshmukh: Thank you for your suggestion. But, I can't do that for the moment..

Comment: `I can't do that`...why not?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sandenay/7jk96gs7/

Comment: @charlietfl: Beacuse my client is quite adamant...Sorry to say that...

Comment: All right then. In @SandeepNayak 's example, replace `blur` with `keyup` and you shall have your desired functionality.

Comment: Added `keyup` event http://jsfiddle.net/sandenay/7jk96gs7/3/

Answer (score 1):

I tried a jQuery solution:

I know its a hack, but I am doing a pattern match after `:` symbol on `blur` event.

Here is what I have done:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var input_value = $("#account_no").val();
  var OriginalStr = input_value.substr(input_value.indexOf(":") + 1, input_value.length);

  //console.log(OriginalStr);
  $("#account_no").on("blur", function() {
    var val = $(this).val();

    //console.log(val);
    var substr = val.substr(val.indexOf(":") + 1, val.length);
    console.log(substr);
    if (substr !== OriginalStr)
      $("#account_no").val(input_value);
    else
      input_value = $("#account_no").val();

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="account_no" value="123abc-123:20122015" />
```

fiddle using `blur` event: http://jsfiddle.net/sandenay/7jk96gs7/1/

fiddle using `keyup` event : http://jsfiddle.net/sandenay/7jk96gs7/3/

Comment: `keyup` works better than `onblur` in this case. imho!